# Is every sub-Hopf algebra a Frobenius extension?

Tags: adjoint-functors, hopf-algebras

Recall that a ring extension $S \subset R$ (i.e. fancy words for saying that $S$ is a subring of $R$) is called a *Frobenius extension* if the restriction functor $\operatorname{Res}:R\text{-mod} \to S\text{-mod}$ is Frobenius, i.e. has isomorphic left and right adjoints.

Let now $H$ be a finite-dimensional Hopf algebra over a field, and $A \subset H$ be a sub-Hopf algebra.
By this I mean that $A$ is a Hopf algebra by restricting the Hopf algebra structure of $H$ to $A$.
The question in the title is:

**Question:** Is $A \subset H$ a Frobenius extension? Or what is an example where it isn't?
$\newcommand{\Res}{\operatorname{Res}}
\newcommand{\Coind}{\operatorname{Coind}}
\newcommand{\Hom}{\operatorname{Hom}}$

It is motivated by the following chain of facts

1. Nichols-Zoeller theorem states that $\Res(H)$ is free.
2. Thus, the right adjoint of $\Res$, called *coinduction*, is exact:
   it is given by $\Coind(N) = \Hom_S(\Res(H), N)$, and thus exact since $\Res(H)$ is projective.
3. As an exact functor, $\Coind$ also possesses a right adjoint (we are dealing with abelian categories here), call that $\Coind^{r.a.}$

Therefore my question is equivalent to

**Question':** Is $\Coind^{r.a.}$ automatically isomorphic to $\Res$? Or are there examples where it isn't?

For group Hopf algebras it should be true, what about the general case?